# pip install in editable mode from a pyproject in a docker container, ModuleNotFoundError not found

Tags: python, docker, pip, dockerfile

When I `pip install -e .` my python package in a container (using `setup.py` and `pyproject.toml`, not requirements.txt), python cannot find my package.
If I remove `-e` from the pip install, so its just `pip install .` then it works in the container.
I added a `pip list` and I see my module installed on the container, yet it cant be used.
Note: I am using a docker volume for my project on the container. I thought this would allow me to edit the files locally without having to restart the container in and editable mode.

Here is my docker-compose

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  myapp:
    container_name: myapp
    build:
      context: ./services/myapp
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./services/myapp/:/usr/src/app/
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    env_file:
      - ./.env/.env.dev.myapp
    networks:
      - myapp-network
networks:
  myapp-network:
    driver: bridge
```

My docker file

```
# pull official base image
FROM python:3.10.7-slim-buster

# set work directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# install system dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y netcat ansible ssh sshpass

# Copy certs over
COPY certs/* /app/

# install dependencies
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -e .

# Show all installed modules
RUN pip list

# run entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh"]
```

After that my entrypoint calls a `manage.py` that is outside of my project and I try to import some moduels with it, But this is where it fails. It cant find those modules.

If I use `pip install -e .` in my python evn outside of the container it works.
Is there a reason why `pip install -e .` wont work in my docker container?

**UPDATE:**
I found that if I go directly into the container and uninstall the module and reinstall it with `pip install -e .` it works.
Is this just a race condition problem with docker volumes?

Comment: How are you creating the container? Where are the library files located? The `-e` flag does not copy the files to `site-packages` so if the repository isn't copied into the container (but site-packages are), then the library won't be available.

Comment: I create the container through docker-compose > Dockerfile, I use a docker volume to get my package onto the container.

Comment: Please be more specific - edit your post to include the relevant Dockerfile code and host file structure.

Comment: I updated my post with the docker-compose.yml entry, and the Dockerfile.

Comment: There is nothing in `/usr/src/app` at build time, is there? docker-compose instructs to mount a volume there, but this only happens at run-time, not at build time, right?

Comment: That was it,  also I needed to direct the pip install -e to my project/ folder. Thanks. Will post a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was two fold.

1. I needed to copy my directory over in the Dockerfile as the volume  is only mounted at run time.
2. Needed to pip install to the actual driectory. I noticed the wrong directory was being used form the pip list output.

Corrected Dockerfile:

```
# pull official base image
FROM python:3.10.7-slim-buster

# set work directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# install system dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y netcat ansible ssh sshpass

# Copy certs over
COPY certs/* /app/

# install dependencies
COPY . /usr/src/app
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -e project/.

# Show all installed modules
RUN pip list

# run entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh"]
```